# Mysql function to replace multiple id with description

Tags: mysql, function, loops, foreach, row

I need some help to create a crazy function!

I got a table called `product` and a table `country`. On this product table, i have a column called `CountriesId` with some id's like `1,2,3,4`.

I need to create a stored function that when i make a select on product table, i can replace the id's returned at CountriesId column with the description from the table `Country`.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Country;
```

Result:

```
CountryId | CountryDescription
1         | U.S.A
2         | Japan
3         | China

SELECT * FROM Product;
```

Result:

```
ProductId | ProductDescription | CountriesId
1         | Product 1          | 1,2,3

SELECT fnIdToDescription(CountriesId) AS Countries FROM Product;
```

Expected Result:
Countries
U.S.A,Japan,China

Maybe it can be made easeally, but i did't find the solution.

Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a function called GROUP_CONCAT() and solved it using a sub-select on ID's with GROUP_CONCAT() on Description column.

Thank's all.

Answer (score 1):

You will be doing a lot better now and in the future if you change your DB design now. It is violating the first normalisation rule.

Remove the `countryIds` column from your `Product` table and create a new table `CountryProduct` that stores the relations between the tables. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE CountryProduct
(
   countryId INT NOT NULL,      `
   productId INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (countryId, productId) 
);
```

Comment: I think you would want a separate table to store all of the country IDs for each product.

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution juergen. The problem is the system is already working and i can't change the database design at this moment. Maybe on a second version. Now, only i can do is find a solution to the actual scenario.

Comment: i was thinking about something like `code DELIMITER $

CREATE FUNCTION fnIdToDescription(id TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE a TEXT;
DECLARE b varchar(50);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Description FROM Country WHERE CountryId IN (SELECT id);

OPEN cur1;
LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO b;
 SET a = CONCAT(a, ', ', b);    
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;

RETURN texto;
END`